# Split String with RegExp

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

The following string has some variables inside:

```
sText := '%CUSTOMER_LASTNAME%%CUSTOMER_PRENAME% - LANG: %LANGUAGE%'
```

I made a custom SPLIT_STRING function and want to get each variable in the String:

```
sStr := SPLIT_STRING(sText,'%');
```

What I now got in loop is:

- null
- CUSTOMER_LASTNAME
- null
- CUSTOMER_PRENAME,
- '- Lang':
- LANGUAGE
- null

What I need:

- CUSTOMER_LASTNAME
- CUSTOMER_PRENAME
- LANGUAGE

Can I perform a split string with an RegExp or how to do this?

TIA 
frgtv10

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can I perform a split string with an RegExp

Yes, you can. Here is an example of how it can be done.

```
    SQL> with t1(col) as(
      2    select '%CUSTOMER_LASTNAME%%CUSTOMER_PRENAME%- LANG: %LANGUAGE%' from dual
      3  )
      4  , ocrs as(
      5     select level as ocr
      6       from ( select max(regexp_count(col, '%[^%]+%')) mxo
      7                from t1
      8             ) s
      9     connect by level <= s.mxo
     10  )
     11  select ltrim(rtrim(regexp_substr(col, '%[^%]+%', 1, o.ocr), '%'), '%') as res
     12    from t1
     13    cross join ocrs o
     14  ;

Result:

    RES
    --------------------
    CUSTOMER_LASTNAME
    CUSTOMER_PRENAME
    LANGUAGE
```

[**SQLFiddle Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/11ee0/1)

Comment: Wow, thats a bit weird for me. Is it possible to put it in a function? Do I really need the SELECT FROM DUAL part for doing this?

Comment: wow.. i need to take a certification particularly for regexp :)

Comment: @frgtv10 The `with` clause is there just to represent sample of data you've provided - (to put it simply, *sort of table replacement*).

Comment: This works, but how to put this in a function to use it maybe like the `SPLIT_STRING` function?

Comment: @ajmalmhd04 lol, maybe SO can start offering certifications.  Until then, here's some [fun reading](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28424/adfns_regexp.htm) to get you going.